# Encounter error when assigning mapping to another

Tags: solidity, mapping

I've declared a mapping `mapping (address => uint) public stakeholderId;` in another contract. I want to copy it from the contract, so I've declared a mapping and want to assign the mapping to it:

```
contract ActivityInterface{
    address CongressAddress = 0x1;
    Congress temp = Congress(CongressAddress);
    mapping (address => uint) stakeholderId = temp.stakeholderId;
}
```

However, why does it show the following error for the line `mapping (address => uint) stakeholderId = temp.stakeholderId;`:

> Type function (address) returns (uint256) is not implicitly
>   convertible to expected type mapping(address => uint256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity generates [getter functions](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#getter-functions) for public state variables.

Those functions can be used to access other contract's state.

In your example, `temp.stakeholderId` is a such autogenerated function. You can call it to get stakeholder id by address:

```
uint id = temp.stakeholderId(someAddress);
```

So, back to error message `temp.stakeholderId` has type `function (address) returns (uint256)` and it can not be converted to `mapping(address => uint256)`.

As to your original intention, maps are reference types, and I don't think it is easy to copy map from one contract to another without some loop.